# how can i deserialize a JSON file in C#?

Tags: json

i want to deserialize a JSON file that has unknown and different feilds, how can i do this?

```
{
"general": [
    {
        "enabled": "yes",
        "port": "5038",
        "bindaddr": "0.0.0.0",
        "displayconnects": "no"
    }
],
"admin": [
    {
        "secret": "admin",
        "deny": "0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0",
        "permit": "0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0",
        "read": "system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,command,dtmf,reporting,cdr,dialplan,originate",
        "write": "system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,command,dtmf,reporting,cdr,dialplan,originate"
    }
],
"phpconfig": [
    {
        "secret": "php[{onfig",
        "deny": "0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0",
        "permit": "127.0.0.1/255.255.255.0",
        "read": "system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,dtmf,reporting,cdr,dialplan",
        "write": "system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,command,reporting,originate"
    }
],
"phpagi": [
    {
        "secret": "phpagi",
        "deny": "0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0",
        "permit": "127.0.0.1/255.255.255.0",
        "read": "system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,dtmf,reporting,cdr,dialplan",
        "write": "system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,command,reporting,originate"
    }
],
"AstTapi": [
    {
        "secret": "AstTapi",
        "deny": "0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0",
        "permit": "127.0.0.1/255.255.255.0",
        "read": "system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user",
        "write": "system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user"
    }
],
"a2billinguser": [
    {
        "secret": "a2billing",
        "deny": "0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0",
        "permit": "127.0.0.1/255.255.255.0",
        "read": "system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,dtmf,reporting,cdr,dialplan",
        "write": "system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,command,reporting,originate"
    }
],
"remote_mgr": [
    {
        "secret": "0chanc3yo",
        "deny": "0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0",
        "permit": "127.0.0.1/255.255.255.0",
        "read": "system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user",
        "write": "system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: how is this question specific to Unix or Linux?  maybe it belongs in [so].

Comment: hi, it's a JSON file and i wand to deserialize it.